# Examples of production Erlang deployments

Tags: erlang, development-environment, scalability, production-environment

**I am currently learning Erlang**

Can SO users give interesting examples of any of their Erlang application deployments?

I want to gain some insight into common Erlang uses past telecomms, and any problems or unexpected benefits Erlang brought during development/deployment.

I hope this will give some broader context and whet the whistle for myself and anyone else jumping into Erlang!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Our first application was a web/sms social network and I wrote a long paper on the subject which can be read [here](http://wadler.blogspot.com/2005/06/service-architectures.html).

Comment: That looks really interesting Gordon. Thank you for your answer :) I wouldn't mind playing with Erlang in a HTTP setting (just from the performance metrics I have seen)

Comment: This topic pretty much died. Thanks Gordon, your links was very informative.

Answer (score 6):

[Who uses Erlang for product development](http://erlang.org/faq/introduction.html#1.5):

- Bluetail/Alteon/Nortel  (distributed,
  fault tolerant email system, SSL
  accelerator)
- Cellpoint (Location-based Mobile
  Services)
- Corelatus (SS7 monitoring).
- dqdp.net (in Latvian) (Web Services).
- Facebook (Facebook chat backend)
- Finnish Meteorological Institute
  (Data acquisition and real-time
  monitoring)
- IDT corp. (Real-time least-cost
  routing expert systems)
- Klarna (Electronic payment systems)
- Mobilearts (GSM and UMTS services)
- Netkit Solutions (Network Equipment
  Monitoring and Operations Support
  Systems)
- Process-one (Jabber Messaging)
- Schlund + Partner (Messaging and
  Interactive Voice Response services)
- Quviq (Software Test Tool)
- RabbitMQ (AMQP Enterprise Messaging)
- T-Mobile (previously one2one)
  (advanced call control services)
- Telia (a telecomms operator)
- Vail Systems (Interactive Voice
  Response systems)
- Wavenet (SS7 and IVR applications)

Comment: Thanks :) Most of those are telecomms related. The IDT example is interesting, as is Quviq

Answer (score 1):

We've built a web app based on an Erlang backend.

Erlang is in charge of the business logic, the security and data store.
The browser communicates exclusively through JSON services with it and do the rendering.

It will be in beta soon, and to give you an idea of the app there is [a video here](http://beebole.com)

There are as well some resources [here](http://beebole.com/erlang) and [here](http://beebole.com/en/blog/category/erlang) about what we learned along the way.

Answer (score 0):

Get to know the the release tools erlang/OTP already provides.

Erlang bootscripts are wonderful for ensuring that all the running applications needed are present and of the correct version. Working within the OTP framework for releases will be much easier than trying to invent your own. Erlang has lots of tools for making sure deployments can be done both live and without breaking running services. The language and runtime are designed for this so they've done a lot of the heavy lifting for you. I've found the tools useful even for small "non-enterprise" apps and deployments.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Jeremy. I was more seeking information on what tasks people have pointed Erlang at past telecomms.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there's always applications like [wings3D](http://www.wings3d.com) which is for 3D modelling. It's not exactly a "deployment", because these sorts of programs are used anywhere from individuals to teams of artists in their pipeline. There are other projects for things like simulation, but I'm not sure how many companies are publicly stating that they use Erlang. As for me, I'm planning to adopt it for my company for industrial automation.